# How to tar files with no extensions?

Tags: linux, tar, wildcards

I have some directories with a varying numbers of files and subdirectories. All files that have no extensions have to be `tar`ed. Their names may change, thus they can not be hardcoded. Subdirectories may also contain a unspecified number of files and subdirectories that are not relevant and should not be included in the archive.

I'd like to be able to do this with a single line, not using any `.sh` scripts, so that this process could be reproduced as portably as possible.

---

Sample directory structure:

```
$ ls -1F

bar-dir/
bar.with.dots
foo-directory/
foo-no-ext
quux.dir/
quux.ext
```

The resulting `tar` should contain only `foo-no-ext` in this case.

---

The closest I've come up with this far is

```
tar -cf archive.tar --exclude=*.* --no-recursion *
```

But, when executed on the sample set, the `archive.tar` still includes the subdirectories (even though empty):

```
$ tar -tf archive.tar

bar-dir/
foo-directory/
foo-no-ext
```

Comment: Using a shell script might be *more* portable than you think. For example, `bash` or `perl` is exactly the same on all systems, while `tar` may be GNU, BSD, Solaris tar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command does what you want:

```
 find * -maxdepth 0 -type f | tar -cf archive.tar --exclude=*.* -T -
```

The `find` command finds all files `*` only in the current directory `-maxdepth 0` that are files `-type f` (not directories, devices or other special files).  The resulting files are passed to tar which excludes the names containing a dot.

Comment: This doesn't accept filenames with spaces. `find ... | tar -T - ...` would be somewhat better.

Comment: @grawity Edited as you suggested, now it allows filenames with spaces.

Comment: I would suggest `-type f` unless you want to find also links, sockets, pipes and device nodes.

Comment: @mugen I took your suggestion and edited the command.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
tar -cf archive.tar `ls|grep "^[^.]*$"`
```

It doesn't expect much out of the shell, but assume that grep exists (I've never seen a system without it).